# How well does the built-in GPU in a Intel Core i5 2500K support unity?

Tags: 11.10, unity, intel-graphics, intel

How well does the built-in GPU in a Intel Core i5 2500K support unity? Will I need a discreet graphics to run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even tough there are many people running Unity3D around with the builtin GPU's from Intel the results can be a bit slow or not as snappy as with a discrete card.

Some people have no complaints over using it but if you feel it is not as fast as you would like then you can always try Unity2D, which will mostly not care what card you are using.

Unity3D's compiz takes a heavy toll in the system's performance and if not compensated with a fast GPU it can feel slow. (It can feel slow even with a dedicated GPU).

Your GPU's driver come directly from Ubuntu repo's and should be installed by default when you install Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly do not need a discrete graphics card to run Unity. I have a laptop with a Core i5-2520M (2.5 GHz, 3 MB cache, dual core) and it runs Unity perfectly.

Unity does use the functionality of the GPU but it has much less demands than a 3D graphics heavy game; you do not need the latest and fastest graphics card for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in GPU in an Intel Core i5 2500K, as that is a CPU.  Some motherboards intended to run a 2500K have a built in GPU, but that is not the same as saying the 2500K has a built in GPU.

Comment: Take a look at http://ark.intel.com/products/52210, specially the "Graphics Specifications" section

Comment: @binW, their specs are misleading.  What the 2500K has are extra instructions that can be used to accelerate graphics operations that would otherwise be slow on a CPU ( but a GPU is still much better at them ).  When paired with some simple 2d graphics hardware on the motherboard and the right driver, basic 3d graphics capability is implemented in software, with no GPU.

Comment: It works together with the the chipset on the motherboard, still the combined result is a GPU and not a graphics card because of the refereed instructions.

Comment: @BrunoPereira, the combined result is modest 3d graphics, not a GPU, which is a specific type of hardware.